# Can we use NumPy in writing a website?

Tags: python, numpy

If I write code with NumPy, can a webserver which run Python 2.5 run the code?
Can we use NumPy as a dynamic language in writing websites of computational nature?

Comment: I mean.. yes?  It's like asking if your website can use division, or strings.

Comment: NumPy is not a language, it's a library. Sounds like you might be either mixed up or trolling.

Answer (score 2):

Yes of course you can.

If you wanted to use straight Python to serve up your HTML pages etc you should look at something like [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) (a fully featured Python web framework) and [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) (a much lighter framework with less implemented features).

As all of these are Python you can install them alongside Numpy in a [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) on your webserver and then just `import numpy` as you would normally in your code to perform the computational work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Your web site will need to be able to run Python code in some way, but if you can `import numpy` then you can use it.